# R: Create a constant color scale for matching factors across dataframes for use in making barcharts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make bar graphs in ggplot2 that visualise the proportion each factor contributes to the whole over multiple 'trips'. In this case, each factor is a taxonomic family of fish. Creating said graphs is easy enough, however, I am trying to make it so that the color scale applies to to all graphs (in this case its 4). Here is an example:

```
x<-split(fish_comp_all, with(fish_comp_all, interaction(fish_comp_all$Dai)), drop = TRUE)
list2env(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
fcs15E<- data.frame(aggregate(Abundance ~ Trip + Family, Dai15E, sum))
fcs15E_total<- data.frame(aggregate(Abundance ~ Trip, Dai15E, sum))
x<-split(fcs15E, with(fcs15E, interaction(fcs15E $Trip)), drop = TRUE)
y<-split(fcs15E_total, with(fcs15E_total, interaction(fcs15E_total$Trip)), drop = TRUE)

n = 6
family_proportion = list()
for (i in seq(n)) {
  family_proportion[[i]]<- data.frame(x[[i]]$Abundance/y[[i]]$Abundance)  
}

n = 6
fam = list()
for (i in seq(n)) {
  fam[[i]]<- cbind(x[[i]], family_proportion[[i]]$x..i...Abundance.y..i...Abundance)
}

fam_prop<- bind_rows(fam, .id = 'sample_period') %>%
  rename_with(~ c('perc_abund'), 5) #%>%

fam_prop$Family<- case_when(fam_prop$perc_abund < 0.05 ~ paste0('Misc'), fam_prop$perc_abund > 0.05 ~ paste0(fam_prop$Family))
fam_prop$total_abund<- fcs15E_total$Abundance[match(fam_prop$Trip, fcs15E_total$Trip)] 

library(RColorBrewer)
myColors <- createPalette(33, c("#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff")) #glasbey.colors(32)
names(myColors) <- levels(names_2021_22$Family)
colScale <- scale_colour_manual(name = "Family",values = myColors)

fam_prop_barchart_15E<- ggplot(fam_prop, aes(x = Trip, y = perc_abund, fill = Family)) + 
  annotate('text', x = 'T1', y = 1.05, label = 'Non-Peak') +
  annotate('text', x = 'T2', y = 1.05, label = 'Peak') +
  annotate('text', x = 'T3', y = 1.05, label = 'Non-Peak') +
  annotate('text', x = 'T4', y = 1.05, label = 'Peak') +
  annotate('text', x = 'T5', y = 1.05, label = 'Non-Peak') +
  annotate('text', x = 'T6', y = 1.05, label = 'Peak') +
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') + colScale + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + theme_bw() +
  xlab('Sampling Trip') + ylab('Proportion') 
plot(fam_prop_barchart_15E)
```

Produces this graph:
[image]

A near identical set of code produces the next graph.
Code:

```
fcs3D<- data.frame(aggregate(Abundance ~ Trip + Family, Dai3D, sum))
fcs3D_total<- data.frame(aggregate(Abundance ~ Trip, Dai3D, sum))
x<-split(fcs3D, with(fcs3D, interaction(fcs3D$Trip)), drop = TRUE)
y<-split(fcs3D_total, with(fcs3D_total, interaction(fcs3D_total$Trip)), drop = TRUE)

n = 2
family_proportion = list()
for (i in seq(n)) {
  family_proportion[[i]]<- data.frame(x[[i]]$Abundance/y[[i]]$Abundance)
}

n = 2
fam = list()
for (i in seq(n)) {
  fam[[i]]<- cbind(x[[i]], family_proportion[[i]]$x..i...Abundance.y..i...Abundance)
}

fam_prop<- bind_rows(fam, .id = 'sample_period') %>%
  rename_with(~ c('perc_abund'), 5) #%>%
fam_prop <- fam_prop %>% mutate(Family = case_when(fam_prop$perc_abund < 0.05 ~ paste0('Misc'), fam_prop$perc_abund > 0.05 ~ paste0(fam_prop$Family)))
fam_prop$total_abund<- fcs3D_total$Abundance[match(fam_prop$Trip, fcs3D_total$Trip)] 

fam_prop_barchart_3D<- ggplot(fam_prop, aes(x = Trip, y = perc_abund, fill = Family)) + 
  annotate('text', x = 'T1', y = 1.05, label = 'Non-Peak') +
  annotate('text', x = 'T4', y = 1.05, label = 'Peak') +
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') + colScale + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + theme_bw() +
  xlab('Sampling Trip') + ylab('Proportion') 
plot(fam_prop_barchart_3D)
```

Graph produced:
[image]

As you can see, the color for 'Cyprinidae' did not remain consistent between the two graphs. This is issue becomes worse when I create plots using only fish families included in the 'misc' category.

Is there a way to create a function that would set 'Cyprinidae' to always be green? I know I can use something that would set all values manually (i.e. colours = c("Cyprinidae" = "green", "B" = "blue", "C" = "red", "D" = "grey")), but there are 33 families in total and am looking for something not as cumbersome and time consuming as assigning everything manually. (also I dont think I could come up with 33 colors).

reprex for both graphs data if needed: 15E:

```
structure(list(No = 1:10, Trip = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1"), Dai = c("Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E", 
"Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E"
), Sample = c("S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", 
"S1", "S1"), Date_S = structure(c(18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 
18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962), class = "Date"), Time_S = structure(c(31800, 
31800, 31800, 31800, 31800, 31800, 31800, 31800, 31800, 31800
), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), Date_E = structure(c(18962, 
18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962
), class = "Date"), Time_E = structure(c(36600, 36600, 36600, 
36600, 36600, 36600, 36600, 36600, 36600, 36600), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), Total_Catch = c(23, 23, 23, 23, 
23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23), Subsample.kg. = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5), Scientific_Name = c("Anabas testudineus", "Cynoglossus microlepis", 
"Boesemania microlepis", "Parambassis wolffii", "Trichopodus trichopterus", 
"Puntioplites proctozysron", "Amblyrhynchichthys micracanthus", 
"Channa striata", "Yasuhikotakia modesta", "Paralaubuca typus"
), Family = c("Anabantidae", "Cynoglossidae", "Sciaenidae", "Ambassidae", 
"Osphronemidae", "Cyprinidae", "Cyprinidae", "Channidae", "Botiidae", 
"Cyprinidae"), Order = c("Perciformes", "Pleuronectiformes", 
"Perciformes", "Perciformes", "Perciformes", "Cypriniformes", 
"Cypriniformes", "Perciformes", "Cypriniformes", "Cypriniformes"
), Abundance = c(5, 9, 15, 9, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 6), weight = c(27.4, 
56, 79.7, 45.2, 7.2, 1.6, 11.4, 11.7, 4.6, 25.4), Date_time_S = structure(c(1638323400, 
1638323400, 1638323400, 1638323400, 1638323400, 1638323400, 1638323400, 
1638323400, 1638323400, 1638323400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "Asia/Bangkok"), Date_time_E = structure(c(1638328200, 
1638328200, 1638328200, 1638328200, 1638328200, 1638328200, 1638328200, 
1638328200, 1638328200, 1638328200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "Asia/Bangkok"), Duration = c(1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 
1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 
1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333
), Time_M = structure(c(34200, 34200, 34200, 34200, 34200, 34200, 
34200, 34200, 34200, 34200), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
    unique_id = c("T1 S1", "T1 S1", "T1 S1", "T1 S1", "T1 S1", 
    "T1 S1", "T1 S1", "T1 S1", "T1 S1", "T1 S1"), DayNight = c("Day", 
    "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day"
    ), date_column = structure(c(18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 
    18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962), class = "Date"), 
    peak = c("Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", 
    "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", 
    "Non-Peak")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

3D:

```
structure(list(No = 163:173, Trip = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1"), Dai = c("Dai3D", "Dai3D", 
"Dai3D", "Dai3D", "Dai3D", "Dai3D", "Dai3D", "Dai3D", "Dai3D", 
"Dai3D", "Dai3D"), Sample = c("S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", 
"S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S4"), Date_S = structure(c(18962, 18962, 
18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962
), class = "Date"), Time_S = structure(c(42000, 42000, 42000, 
42000, 42000, 42000, 42000, 42000, 42000, 42000, 42000), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), Date_E = structure(c(18962, 18962, 
18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962
), class = "Date"), Time_E = structure(c(46200, 46200, 46200, 
46200, 46200, 46200, 46200, 46200, 46200, 46200, 46200), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), Total_Catch = c(0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 
0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758), Subsample.kg. = c(0.758, 
0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 
0.758), Scientific_Name = c("Barbonymus gonionotus", "Tenualosa thibaudeaui", 
"Cynoglossus microlepis ", "Labiobarbus leptocheilus", "Amblyrhynchichthys micracanthus", 
"Coilia lindmani", "Puntioplites proctozysron", "Gymnostomus siamensis", 
"Paralaubuca typus", "Parambassis wolffii", "Pangasius bocourti"
), Family = c("Cyprinidae", "Clupeidae", "Cynoglossidae", "Cyprinidae", 
"Cyprinidae", "Engraulidae", "Cyprinidae", "Cyprinidae", "Cyprinidae", 
"Ambassidae", "Pangasiidae"), Order = c("Cypriniformes", "Clupeiformes", 
"Pleuronectiformes", "Cypriniformes", "Cypriniformes", "Clupeiformes", 
"Cypriniformes", "Cypriniformes", "Cypriniformes", "Perciformes", 
"Siluriformes"), Abundance = c(1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 11, 13, 7, 2, 
2), weight = c(118.4, 92, 81.8, 77, 9.2, 10.6, 20.4, 146.2, 54.4, 
10.4, 23.6), Date_time_S = structure(c(1638333600, 1638333600, 
1638333600, 1638333600, 1638333600, 1638333600, 1638333600, 1638333600, 
1638333600, 1638333600, 1638333600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "Asia/Bangkok"), Date_time_E = structure(c(1638337800, 
1638337800, 1638337800, 1638337800, 1638337800, 1638337800, 1638337800, 
1638337800, 1638337800, 1638337800, 1638337800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Bangkok"), Duration = c(1.16666666666667, 
1.16666666666667, 1.16666666666667, 1.16666666666667, 1.16666666666667, 
1.16666666666667, 1.16666666666667, 1.16666666666667, 1.16666666666667, 
1.16666666666667, 1.16666666666667), Time_M = structure(c(44100, 
44100, 44100, 44100, 44100, 44100, 44100, 44100, 44100, 44100, 
44100), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), unique_id = c("T1 S4", 
"T1 S4", "T1 S4", "T1 S4", "T1 S4", "T1 S4", "T1 S4", "T1 S4", 
"T1 S4", "T1 S4", "T1 S4"), DayNight = c("Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day"), date_column = structure(c(18962, 
18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 18962, 
18962), class = "Date"), peak = c("Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", 
"Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", 
"Non-Peak", "Non-Peak")), row.names = 163:173, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is atypical in `ggplot2` but can be done by extending the color scales with `ggproto`
For clarity, the reason this occurs in `ggplot2` is that a color palette is given to the scale which has a maximum
number of values to choose from (assuming it is descrete). The color values returned depends on the number of colors
requested for certain palettes (this is true for `ggplot2`’s default palette). This is why you see different colors appear
with different number of levels between figures.

The source code generally only considers how many distinct colors must be requested from the palette, not the actual values
themselves.

That being said, that doesn’t mean we can’t do what you may want. Here I will try and make a palette function that takes
in values, and then matches against a table to return specific colors.

This function takes in values (colors) and a set of keys (or alternatively name the colors) and returns
a function that provides the key values.

```r
library(ggplot2)
match_pal <- function(values, keys = NULL) {
  if (is.null(keys)) {
    if (is.null(names(values))) {
      stop("keys must be assigned or values must be named")
    }
    keys <- names(values)
  } 
  if (length(keys)!=length(values)) {
    stop("keys must be same length as values")
  }
  names(values) <- keys
  function(n) {
    u_n <- unique(n)
    values[match(u_n, keys)]
  }
}
```

In order for the above palette to work with ggplot2’s scales, we will need to change the source code
of the `ggproto()`’s `$map` method

```r
manual_scale_match <- function(palette, aesthetics, values = NULL, breaks = waiver(), ..., limits = NULL) {
  
  ggproto(
    NULL,
    ggplot2:::manual_scale(aesthetic = aesthetics,
                           values = values, breaks = breaks,
                           ...,
                           limits = limits),
    map = function(self, x, limits = self$get_limits()) {
      pal <- self$palette(x)
      self$palette.cache <- pal
      pal_match <- pal[match(as.character(x), names(pal))]
      pal_match
    },
    palette = palette
  )
}
```

next we can make some easy user facing functions

```r
scale_color_match <- function(palette, ..., aesthetics = "colour", breaks = waiver(), na.value = "grey50") {
  manual_scale_match(palette = palette, aesthetics = aesthetics, breaks = breaks, na.value = na.value, ...)
}

scale_fill_match <- function(palette, ..., aesthetics = "fill", breaks = waiver(), na.value = "grey50") {
  manual_scale_match(palette = palette, aesthetics = aesthetics, breaks = breaks, na.value = na.value, ...)
}

my_palette <-  match_pal(c('setosa' = "red", 'versicolor' = "purple", 'virginica' = 'pink'))

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_match(palette = my_palette)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(subset(iris, !Species %in% "versicolor"), aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_match(palette = my_palette)
```

[image]

Now you mentioned that it may be hard to even find 33 colors, and I agree,
but if you want to use the default pallete, you can call that directly like the following:

```r
ggplot2_default_palette <- scales::hue_pal()
# return 33 colors from palette
ggplot2_default_palette(33)
#>  [1] "#F8766D" "#F07E4D" "#E78619" "#DB8E00" "#CE9500" "#BF9C00" "#AEA200"
#>  [8] "#9AA800" "#82AD00" "#64B200" "#32B600" "#00BA38" "#00BD5C" "#00BF78"
#> [15] "#00C091" "#00C1A7" "#00C0BB" "#00BECD" "#00BADE" "#00B5ED" "#00AEF9"
#> [22] "#00A6FF" "#619CFF" "#9191FF" "#B385FF" "#CD79FF" "#E16FF8" "#EF67EB"
#> [29] "#F962DB" "#FF61CA" "#FF63B6" "#FF68A0" "#FD6F88"
```

Now with the above, you could assign the families to distinct values with `my_palette <- match_pal(df$Family, ggplot2_default_palette(33))`

<sup>Created on 2023-07-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I've been playing with this and it seems like it would work, however, it doesn't get around me having to manually assign each family a color. Using the bottom-most script (my_palette <- match_pal(df$Family, ggplot2_default_palette(33)) turns my_palette into a function that needs some sort of data frame input.

Comment: The whole idea of this method is that you know all possible categories that you want to color. You cache this in a function returned by `match_pal()`, and then supply that function as the palette to `scale_color_match()` or `scale_fill_match()`. As I explained, `ggplot2`'s default method for deciding the colors used depends on the number of categories supplied to the aesthetic at the time of rendering. The only way to make categories consistent between figures is manually matching to a predefined list.